# Autonomous navigation with Turtlebot3 algorithm

Tags: ros, c++, exploration, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
i tried to develop in C++ with success (basically i'm still a beginner with ROS development) a way for autonomous exploration of n turtlebot3  in an unknown environment (like turtlebot3 house for example). The algorithm is too much "simple",basically i check the laserscan distance from an obstacle and if obstacle distance is less than 0.5 meter robots turn left by 90 degrees.

What i'm looking for now is a more sophisticated algorithm to implement in C++ and an algorithm that "turn aroung" fixed and mobile obstacles (like walking human for example)

I found the relaxed A* algorithm on github but it's useless for me cause it's based on well known map and find the optimal path from a start to a goal point.
Suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296269/autonomous-navigation-with-turtlebot3-algorithm/) by [kenhero](https://answers.ros.org/users/34341/kenhero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2018-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I've had a lot of luck with this [autonomous exploration package explore_light](https://github.com/hrnr/m-explore) on my turtlebot3. It is an improved version of the frontier_exploration package. Maybe it's source code will provide some inspiration for you if you'd rather build your own.

---

Originally posted by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) with karma: 95 on 2018-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1